# MySQL Query Delegation / Transfer

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, replication, master-slave

Does MySQL have query delegation system for the master / slave replication. Or is there any way in programming by which I can achieve same.

I want to make SELECT queries go to SLAVE and every other to MASTER.

I am using Zend PHP which uses DB object from Registry everywhere on site.

Answer (score 2):

No, Zend Framework has no direct support for query delegation.

I did a talk about this last October at the Zend Conference, where I talked about read/write splitting use cases, and demonstrated a Doctrine2 class to handle read/write splitting.

- [Read / Write Splitting with MySQL and PHP](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/read-write-split)

There's also a plugin for the PHP mysqlnd driver, which has a plugin for read/write splitting.  This may be relatively easy to integrate into a ZF application.

- http://pecl.php.net/package/mysqlnd_ms

Answer (score 1):

You should do this at the application layer, as PHP has no built-in support for this.

[MySQL Proxy](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-proxy.html) might also do what you want.